# Como fazer várias requisições em paralelo no axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Eu tenho duas urls para fazer requisição: https://api.tuuris/cities e https://api.tuuris/expenses

Gostaria de fazer requisições de ambas em paralelo, atualmente eu tenho feito separadamente como no código abaixo:

```
  axios
  .get('https://api.tuuris/cities')
  .then(response => {
    this.info = response.data
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    this.errored = true
  })
```

Answer (score 7):

Basta forneça um array para o método `axios.all`.

Depois utilize o método `axios.spread`, que converte um array para múltiplos argumentos.

[`$npm install axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```
  axios.all([
    axios.get('https://api.tuuris/cities'),
    axios.get('https://api.tuuris/expenses')
    ]).then(axios.spread((citiesRes, expensesRes) => {
      this.cities = citiesRes.data
      this.expenses = expensesRes.data
 }))
```